# No focus on a window child to CView

Tags: mfc, mousewheel, cview

I've created a simple MFC MDI application. Then I've created a DLL which implements a simple window (inherited from `CWnd`). I want it to be a child of `CView` window in my application. So when the application starts and the view is created I create my window passing a handle of `CView` as a parent.

It works fine except for the mouse wheel issue: the focus is on the `CView` window (though my window covers the entire client area) and thus my window doesn't receive `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages.
`SetFocus()` after the creation doesn't help.

Is there any correct way other than subclassing/hooking the parent to fix it?
And I want it to be done in DLL.

P.S.
My window is for OpenGL rendering and I want it to be as much self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: Does your window have the `WS_TABSTOP` [Window Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx)?

Comment: That was my first guess. No, it doesn't help.

Comment: so your window covers the whole client area of its parent (that is a CView)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I click it

Comment: I even have a "focus viewer" tool (which just renders on desktop DC a handle of current focused window). Clicking on my window doesn't change the focus (or,  at least, it is not visible). 
I am now considering to investigate it deeper by subclassing `CView` window and watching its `WM_SETFOCUS`. Just to understand maybe it is the behaviour of MFC's MDI application windows...

Comment: Does you handle WM_NCHITTEST correctly?